# How can you configure a system to be bootable from most modern systems?

Tags: boot-loader, bios, uefi, bootable

How can a Linux system be installed on a portable storage medium so that both BIOS systems (e.g. a ThinkPad) and EFI systems (e.g. a Mac Mini) can boot to it?

The reason I ask is because I tried installing Debian onto my portable hard drive with an MBR and GRUB. The BIOS systems I tried booted fine from the drive, but when I tried to boot a Mac Mini (EFI) from it the system did not even detect the drive as a boot medium.

Is there an easy way to install a system that both interfaces will detect and boot from?

Answer (score 0):

For (U)EFI you need a [separate EFI partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition) - GRUB v2 is able to install itself as an EFI boot target (apart from the traditional MBR way of things). However, I'm not sure, whether it can be configured to provide both modes from a single configuration file.

As a side note, you might also want to consider using [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_partition_table) with a hybrid MBR (if you're not doing so yet).

Comment: Hybrid MBR is a hideous hack with quite some data loss potential... and BIOS-booted Linux can use GPT partitions just fine.

Comment: @MichaelShigorin if it's done right it should be fine. One doesn't always want to use a single medium just for Linux (think of a special partition for data that should be visible on systems not understanding GPT).

Answer (score 0):

Well technically you can (install all OSes in EFI mode and add BIOS mode bootloaders for those you want to) but I'd recommend against that waste of time since you'll likely get bored to switch modes quite soon; if a single OS requires EFI you're better off going EFI and using [refind](http://refind.sf.net/) or [refit](http://refit.sf.net/).

Mind that Debian 7.0 installer beta4 had some troubles installing GRUB in EFI mode (those should have some more or less easy workaround but IIRC are still in 7.0.0 release).

In case you'd like to check whether it works out for you try openSUSE 12.2/12.3 or ALT Linux 7.0, I've tested the former and added UEFI support to the latter.  Getting Debian there should present no huge problem upon having read [Rod's book on EFI](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html) too.

Comment: The problem is what to do, when there are two devices for which you can't switch modes (between EFI and MBR), each stuck in a different mode and you need to boot both.